# 12 V, 2-pin power socket identification

Tags: identification, connector, socket, power-connector

I’m trying to find a replacement 12 V, 2-pin plug socket for my Campingaz TE 28 LC Cooler. The socket is 22 mm wide x 15 mm deep x 13 mm high.

I can find plenty of power cords but no sockets to plug into. What type of socket is this, so I can look for a replacement?

The broken socket looks like this -

[image: Broken Socket]

The pin measurements are 11 mm in the center and 3 mm in diameter.

Pictures of the cord ends are below -

[image: 2] [image: 3]

Comment: What is the pin spacing and pin diameter? Have you a photo of the matching cord end?

Comment: https://www.hesta.pl/en/accessories-and-spare-parts-to-rv-camping-refrigerators/534-dc-12v-24v-inlet-socket-for-portable-refrigerator.html

Comment: Looks similar to a IEC320-C8, if so the pins should be 8.6 mm (centers).

Comment: Just to be clear, the  IEC320-C8 is an AC connector. OP's connector is a DC connector and is not an  IEC320-C8.

Comment: If you are unlucky it’s custom. Perhaps standard size pins though.